# Using git to merge changes in a manually-copied directory

Tags: git, git-merge

At work I keep a backup of a large directory on our remote VPS using git. Because I live in a very remote town with poor, expensive internet, I cannot copy this repo over the internet. Instead, when I started working from home, I brought a copy of the directory on an external drive (unfortunately without the ".git" subdirectory).

I have made about 10kb worth of changes to files in my home copy of the directory. I would like to merge these in to the git repo on the remote server **without** transferring the whole directory over the internet.

Steps so far:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial"
git remote add VPS [SSH_ADDRESS]
git remote show VPS   # successfully connects to remote
```

Now I'd like to merge the 10kb of changes I've made locally without transferring the GB of data that are unchanged.

Steps I've tried but failed:

```
git push VPS   # can't because there are non-integrated remote changes
git fetch VPS  # starts downloading GBs of data
```

Not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky approach that tries to transfer as little data as possible, not using git's transport methods, that may or may not work:

- generate patches of your local work (`git format-patch`)
- compress those patches (`tar` or `zip`)
- send them to to the remote server (`scp` or `rsync`)
- login to the remote server (`ssh`)
- apply the patches (`unzip`/`tar` followed by `git apply`), fix conflicts and edit the history to your liking

This will leave your local copy out of sync, as before.

---

Assuming that the "GBs of data" are large files and not many small changes/files, you can circumvent having to store them in the actual git repo.

There are multiple approaches to this problem, of which I have tried neither, but here are some pretty well known:

- Git lfs (large file storage): https://git-lfs.github.com/
- Git annex: https://git-annex.branchable.com/

Comment: Manually generating and copying patches is a workable solution to the question I posted, thank you. Git-annex, on the other hand, seems to be an even better approach to achieving what I was attempting. Thanks for the lead!